# JavaFX app using retrofit async request quitting very slowly

Tags: java, javafx, retrofit, okhttp, retrofit2

I'm developing a JavaFX app with Java 8 and for api requests I'm using retrofit 2.1.0 with converter-gson 2.1.0.

If I make the synchronous request:

```
Patient p = Core.api.getPatient(2).execute().body();
```

Everything works fine, but if I do the asynchronous version:

```
Core.api.getPatient(2).enqueue(new Callback<Patient>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Patient> call, Response<Patient> response) {
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Patient> call, Throwable t) {
        // Nothing
    }
});
```

Everything also works out correctly (it prints "DONE"). However when I quit the application using the standard JavaFX call `Platform.exit()` the UI closes but the application lingers open still and will only exit after ~40 seconds.

If I just do `System.exit(0)` everything works as intended so I'm guessing this might be some threading issue but I'm not sure.

Anyone have an idea on what might be wrong?

**EDIT**:

I found out that after doing `Platform.exit()` a few threads, with names like `RMI TCP Connection(2)` keep alternating and using 100% of the CPU.

Comment: You could try to wrap the async version in a daemon `Thread` like:   `Thread th = new Thread(() -> {/*Async Call here*/});   th.setDaemon(true); th.start();`. Just an idea.

Comment: @DVarga I'm not sure but I think that, while the callback executes on the main thread, the actual request happens on a background thread. EDIT: I just tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OkHttp uses two thread pools that keep threads alive for 60 seconds after use. You can shut em down with force by calling shutdown on the dispatcher's executor and by calling evictAll on the connection pool.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution indeed!